We now have 1,000 Questions! --- August 6th 2013
I just noticed we passed another site milestone: 1,000 Questions.
We reached 500 questions in mid-September 2012.
More importantly, putting aside the flurry of activity around the site beta, the site has the healthiest site statistics it has ever seen. Of particular importance the questions per day has been steadily rising from lows of around 1 per day to 3+ per day while the answer rate has stayed relatively constant. I look forward to when we get the question rate above 5 per day assuming we can keep quality and and the answer rate to a reasonable level.
Hopefully Josh will bake another cake :-)



I think it's Mien's turn to bake us something ;-)
